# Повторы в SQL запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, отладка

Никак не пойму почему происходят повторы в выдаче этого запроса:

```
SELECT `conversions`.`sub_id_1` ,
`offers`.`client_payout` AS `profit` , 
`conversions`.`transaction_id` 
FROM `conversions` , `offers` , `users` 
WHERE `offers`.`id` = `conversions`.`sub_id_2` 
AND `users`.`sponsor` = 3
```

Запрос рабочий, но он выводит информацию с повторами:

```
sub_id_1    profit  transaction_id
1296611152  50  10235b75ba2f9efe80741ff33b5a1e
1296611152  50  10235b75ba2f9efe80741ff33b5a1e
1296611152  50  10235b75ba2f9efe80741ff33b5a1e
12619922412 4   1028580b092280cff234456733d553
12619922412 4   1028580b092280cff234456733d553
12619922412 4   1028580b092280cff234456733d553
```

*В идеале необходимо сделать сумму `profit` по каждому пользователю `sub_id_1` *

Comment: А если использовать SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: @Den, спасибо, помогло. (можете преобразовать в ответ)

Comment: @Shilgen На самом деле у вас в запросе более серьезная проблема. Вы перемножаете все записи выбранные из первых двух таблиц на _все_ записи из `users` с `sponsor=3`. Вы видимо забыли добавить условие которое как то связывает `users` с остальными таблицами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем запросе нет связи между conversins и users. Из последней строки вопроса следует, что conversions.sub_id_1 указывает на пользователя. Если это так, то сумма по каждому пользователю вычисляется как:

```
SELECT 
  `conversions`.`sub_id_1` AS `user_id`,
  SUM(`offers`.`client_payout`) AS `profit`
FROM 
  `conversions` JOIN 
  `offers`ON `offers`.`id` = `conversions`.`sub_id_2`
GROUP BY `conversions`.`sub_id_1`
```

а если добавить ограничение по users.sponsor, как у вас в вопросе, то придется добавить еще одну связь:

```
SELECT 
  `conversions`.`sub_id_1` AS `user_id`,
  SUM(`offers`.`client_payout`) AS `profit`
FROM 
  `conversions` JOIN 
  `offers`ON `offers`.`id` = `conversions`.`sub_id_2`JOIN 
  `users`ON `users`.`id` = `conversions`.`sub_id_1`
WHERE `users`.`sponsor` = 3
GROUP BY `conversions`.`sub_id_1`
```